# Can I check a unique record, except for the edited one AND except for those that have status = 0, in Laravel validator?

Tags: php, laravel, validation

Can I check a unique record, except for the edited one AND except for those that have status = 0?

Something as :

```php
return [
    'contract' => [
        'required',
        'integer',
        Rule::unique('table')
           ->ignore($this->id)
           ->where('contract', $this->contract)
           ->andWhere('status', $this->plan_contract)],           
  /**SOMETHING MORE**/
];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-unique), you can.

But you should a bit rewrite your code:

```php
return [
    'contract' => [
        'required',
        'integer',
        Rule::unique('table')->ignore($this->id)->where(function ($query) {
            return $query
                ->where('contract', $this->contract)
                ->where('status', $this->plan_contract)
        }),
    ];
];
```